# How to get FPS of the video played by MediaPlayer when using a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I am using `MediaPlayer` to play video which can be zommed in and out and am trying to see if there is any difference in the performance between using a `SurfaceView` and a `TextureView` for the player's output.

For the `TextureView`, I used `SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` to know when a frame is shown and thus compute the FPS.

However, I can't find a way to do something similar when using a `SurfaceView`. I tried creating my own class extending `SurfaceView` and overloading `onDraw()`, but it looks like `onDraw()` is never called when playing the movie.

Any idea if and how this can be achieved?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getMetrics()
For android 8.0